# Accessing individual elements' characters using an array parameter in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, parameters

Just started c++ and I'm working on making blackjack. I've set it up so a player's hand is a string of cards, ex: hand[1] = ❤2 hand[2] = ❤J

I've made a function to add up the values of all of the cards in the cards array but i'm running into a problem:

```
int handValue(string hand[]){
    int handSum;

    //returns value of total amount of cards in hand+1
    int numCards = nextCard(hand);
    string value;
    for (int i = 0; i < numCards ; i++){
        //Checks the second character of a card to find a value (1,2,3...T,J,Q,K)
        string value = hand[i][1];
        if (value == "T" || value == "J"|| value == "Q"  || value == "K") {
            handSum += 10;
        }
    }
    return handSum;
}
```

This line is where I'm having the problem:

```
string card = hand[i][1];
```

Yielding the error:

> Invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'.

Why exactly am I getting this error and how do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Consider cleaning up the indentation of your code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hands[i][1]` returns a `char` and there is no constructor of the `std::string` class that takes a single `char` as a parameter.

A string is not needed here, you can just use a `char` type instead:

```
    char value = hands[i][1];
    if (value == 'T' || value == 'J'|| value == 'Q'  || value == 'K') 
        handSum += value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to be aware of the `types` of your variables. c++ is a `strongly typed` language that will distinguish the difference between `one char` and `an array of chars`. Dont be confused by the `const char *` yet... think of it as your array.

```
char fullValue[] = hand[i]; //gets the element at position i
char oneLetter = fullValue[1]; //gets char 1 from our fullValue array
```